# how can i fill out the CSV attribute to extract IFC classification code from blenderbim IFC attribute feature?

Tags: csv, export, classification, ifc

I need an example of how to fill out the CSV attribute field shown in the image below to extract IFC classification code
[classification imput code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkXV5.png)

i had try with the following syntaxis:
IfcClassificationReference
ClassificationReference
classificationreference
Classification
ifcclassification
ifcreference

can someone help me to solve this issue?